# Using OAuth2 to access YouTube api in Android

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working on an app that is supposed to go out and grab analytics data from a users YouTube account.
I am able to retrieve the authorization code from Google using the below url inside a webview in my app.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly&approval_prompt=force&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=762546229188.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline
```

I retrieve the code from the title of the page and then cut off the success using Java's substring method. 
However, when I go to get the access token it will only return `"error" : "invalid_grant"`

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); //new HTTP client
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"); //where to post to
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); //construct the values to hand to Google
        Log.v("KUZMA", arg0[0]); //personal logcat message
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", arg0[0])); //in arg0[0] lives the auth code
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", CLIENT_ID)); //I store the Client_id as a static variable at the beginning of my class
        //Log.v("Kuzma", CLIENT_ID);
        //pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "*******"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "http://localhost"));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code")); //Leave this line how it is   
        String responseBody = null;
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("KUZMA", responseBody); // That just logs it into logCat
        //output.setText("something happened?");
        return null;
```

So I guess my biggest issue is that I don't have a client secret but it is not provided to me by Google for an installed application. Is there a way around this? I have also played with Google Play Services and can't get that working either, but if you know how that works that would be great too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don’t say it, this looks like an Android App.  So you need to go use GoogleAuthUtil to give you the token for the scope; start here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html

Comment: Yeah, I should have come back and said I figured it out but 5 o'clock rolled around and I was done :) I am using GoogleAuthUtil in conjunction with the AccountPicker to generate and use the tokens. Thanks. Also, I did mention Android in the title, and in the tags. I thought that was clear but thanks again.